# Measure types in SPSS

Tags: spss, mean, ordinal-data

What type of measure would a variable containing only means be? Would it be a scalar variable? This variable was created to combine several other variables and make it continuous. These variables were all asking for a ranking on several different categories but over the same topic.

Comment: Could you please explain the sense in which "scalar" is a type of "measure" and what any of this might have to do with SPSS?  What statistical question do you have?

Comment: SPSS is what I'm using and not sure if it is different in other software. Scale would be interval and ratio e.g. temperature. However, if a variable only contains means taken from other variables, what type is this? There is nominal (categorical), ordinal (Likert scale-type), and scale.

Comment: (1) If an answer depends on software, the question likely isn't on topic here. (2) You cannot tell from the information given.  The fact you're taking means suggests the original variables were of interval or ratio type, but they could have been of many other types (such as images) and it's possible in most software to take means of variables of *any* type. How you characterize the type of the resulting variable depends on what it represents, what you're trying to achieve, what model you are using, and what procedures you are running. That's why you need to ask a *statistical* question.

Comment: How is this not statistics? There were 7 questions that asked for a ranking from 1-8, making them ordinal variables. The means were taken from each and put into a single variable in order to make it continuous and run regression. Are you saying since the original variables from which the means were taken was ordinal then the new variable is ordinal?

Comment: Good arguments, depending on circumstances, can be advanced that the mean could be ordinal, it could be interval, it could be ratio, or it could be meaningless.  I still don't see any actual statistical question, because the issue of what type you declare a variable to be in SPSS or any other language does not seem to have any statistical meaning.

Comment: If I choose the wrong variable type it can affect results when running tests. What other information is needed????

Comment: It's hard to see how it could affect results: a test is a calculation, pure and simple.  If the results are affected, that is because whatever you are doing in the software is changing the test itself.  This continues to sound like a software issue.

Comment: Well it isn't. Nevermind. Have a nice day.